# How to use Validation for Custom component within EditForm

Tags: blazor

I have used Validation in EditForm (For Combobox/Textbox etc).It works fine as per my requirement (when Click on submit button).When I use Custom Component within EditForm,the validation message is still showing even when we enter some value.Please advise how to use validation message for custom component

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <MaterialSearchVertical @ref="materialSearchVertical" EditEnabled="@EditEnabled" MaterialTypeID="materialRequestDetailDisplaySetup.MaterialTypeID"
                                                PurchaseTypeID="materialRequestSetup.PurchaseTypeID"
                                                MaterialSKUID="materialRequestDetailDisplaySetup.MaterialSKUID"
                                                MaterialTypeLoad=" AND A.ReferenceDetailsCode in ('SUMAT','MNT','HLTS') "
                                                EventCallBackMaterialSearch="MaterialSearchEventCallBack"></MaterialSearchVertical>
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => materialRequestDetailDisplaySetup.MaterialSKUID)" />
                            </div>
```

Note:-

Answer (score 0):

probably your custom component is not properly bound to the Property you're validating, so when you change the value, that new value is not updated in the model Property (MaterialSKUID);
or the custom component is not calling: `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged`

usually you should have `@bind-Value="PropertyName"` which should ensure the component is bound correctly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0